# how to use collection factory method in intelliJ with java 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, collections, build.gradle

as the question title, I want to use collection factory method such as 'Map.of("string", Object) in java 8 on intelliJ IDEA(Community Version).

I'm aware that it supports in java 9 version, but I've seen that using collection factory method is possible via maven dependency of 'org.codehaus.groovy' in pom.xml on eclipse.

For this reason, I assume that it is also possible to use collection factory method on intelliJ with gradle in a way.

If there is to do any for this, please give me answers.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Provide a link to the collection factory method you discuss in second paragraph.

Comment: It was an youtube video in Korean. Is that okay if I still let you know the link?

Comment: If there are displays of the code readable in English, then yes. As your Question is currently written, what you describe sounds impossible. I suspect you misinterpreted what the video was telling you. So seeing the original source material might be helpful, if enough of it is readable in English.

Comment: Check point - 17:50~18:50 link - https://youtu.be/_GuMbMnzHe8

Answer (score 2):

If you want to the functionality of classes added to Java 9, choose from:

- Use Java 9
- Use similar functionality provided in your version of Java
- Add a library providing similar functionality

You ruled out the first.

The second approach would be the use of [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-) to produce an unmodifiable map as produced by `Map.of`.

```
Map< String , Object > mapModifiable = new HashMap<>() ;
mapModifiable.add( "dog" , whatever ) ;
mapModifiable.add( "cat" , whatever ) ;
Map< String , Object > mapUnmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableMap( mapModifiable ) ;
```

The third approach requires finding and choosing a third-party library. There are at least two offering nonmodifiable maps as produced by `Map.of`. They may also support the convenient literal syntax provided by `Map.of`.

- [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/)
- [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava)

[Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) may be a third, but I am not familiar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer first of all! I'd rather use the given api method 'put' as default or use a library like what you mentioned. Otherwise, I guess I should upgrade java version 8 to 9. Thanks again, sir.

Comment: @JihwangKim Current version is Java 15, with Java 16 due next month. The current long-term support (LTS) versions are Java 8 and 11. Good stuff keeps arriving in each release, like [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) in 16. Generally no reason to avoid upgrading, but of course you should test first.

Comment: thank you so much, I'll keep that in mind!